# How can I tell what ec2 pricing model I have running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance as a windows-bastion.  When I launched it initially I chose to run it as a Spot instance.  Later that day I stopped it as my work was done.
  Today I want to start up that EC2 instance so from the EC2 console I selected Acions->Instance State->Start.
  It is running nicely.

But...  **How can I tell if it is running as a Spot instance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the region of interest, open the console, then open the EC2 section. On the left under "Instances" select "Spot Requests."  If there's nothing there, you probably are not running any spot instances in that region.

You can also obtain this information on the command line with

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests
```